# Why is draw_picture called so many times?

Tags: gtk, vala

When I run the following programme:

```
//compile: valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 sample.vala
using Gtk;

public class Main : Object
{
    private Window window;
    private Gdk.Pixbuf pixbuf;
    private DrawingArea da1;

    public Main()
    {
        window = new Window();
        window.destroy.connect (main_quit);
        pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf.from_file("sample.jpg");
        var box = new Box (Orientation.VERTICAL, 5);
        da1 = new DrawingArea();
        da1.set_hexpand(true);
        da1.set_vexpand(true);
        da1.draw.connect((context) => draw_picture(context, pixbuf));
        box.pack_start (da1, true, true, 0);
        window.add (box);
        window.show_all();
    }


    bool draw_picture(Cairo.Context cr, Gdk.Pixbuf pixbuf)
    {
        print("draw_picture\n");
        int width  = da1.get_allocated_width();
        int height = da1.get_allocated_height();

        var temp = pixbuf.scale_simple(width, height, Gdk.InterpType.BILINEAR);
        Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf (cr, temp, 0, 0);
        cr.paint ();
        
        return false;
    }


    static int main(string[] args)
    {
        Gtk.init(ref args);
        var app = new Main();
        Gtk.main();

        return 0;
    }

}
```

after start I can see 'draw_picture' printed 2 times. When I switch window to terminal, it's displayed additional 7 times. Can anyone explain why and recommend some good book explaining the details?

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer that question for sure, you would need to look at how your window manager works. Probably the redraws that occur when you switch to another window are due to the widget gaining the `:backdrop` pseudoclass when its window ceases to be the active window.

In general a widget's `draw` signal is invoked whenever the window manager needs to redraw a portion of the window that includes the widget, and also whenever the widget's active style changes.

If your widget is expensive to redraw then you can avoid drawing the whole thing when it's not necessary. The Cairo context's clip region will be set to the portion which needs redrawing.